# python shuffling with a parameter to get the same result

Tags: python

```
import random
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
random.shuffle(x)
print x
```

I know how to shuffle a list, but is it possible to shuffle it with a parameter such that the shuffling produces the same result every time?

Something like;

```
random.shuffle(x,parameter)
```

and the result is the same for this parameter. 
Say parameter is `4` and the result is `[4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5]` every time.

Comment: Use the `random.seed()` function.

Comment: changing the seed pollutes the randomness of your entire program.  **do not** do it lightly.

Comment: @Eevee: Which is why you can create new instances of `random.Random` and call `seed` on _them_ (or just pass the seed as an initializer).

Answer (score 237):

As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#module-random) explains:

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the random.Random class. You can instantiate your own instances of Random to get generators that don’t share state.

So, you can just create your own `random.Random` instance, with its own seed, which will not affect the global functions at all:

```
>>> import random
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> random.Random(4).shuffle(x)
>>> x
[4, 6, 5, 1, 3, 2]
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> random.Random(4).shuffle(x)
>>> x
[4, 6, 5, 1, 3, 2]
```

(You can also keep around the `Random` instance and re-`seed` it instead of creating new ones over and over; there's not too much difference.)

Comment: Nice solution! +1 for not affecting the global functions

Answer (score 51):

You can set the `seed` (which accepts the `parameter`) of your random generator, which will determinize your shuffling method

```
import random
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
random.seed(4)
random.shuffle(x)
print x
```

and the result should be always

```
[2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 1]
```

In order to "rerandomize" the rest of the code you can simply reseed your random number generator with system time by running

```
random.seed()
```

after your "deterministic" part of code

Comment: note that this will pollute the results of every function in the `random` module for the rest of your program.  passing the second argument to `shuffle` will only affect that one call.

Comment: Yes, this is an important note, even though you could simply run `random.seed()` again after shuffle to reinitialize it to the system time.

Comment: That's still overly complicated and not very robust. (What if you have multiple threads? What if there's an exception before you get around to re-`seed`-ing?) This is exactly why you can construct new instances of `random.Random`, so you don't have to muck with the global instance.

Answer (score 11):

Shuffling with a fixed value for `random` does NOT work well! Example:

```
from random import shuffle
v = sum([[k] * 100 for k in range(10)], [])
print v[:40]
shuffle(v, random = lambda: 0.7)
print v[:40]
```

Gives the output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 9]
```

It's similar for other seeds - not very random (at first sight anyway... hard to prove). This is because `random` is not a seed - it is reused many times. Demonstration:

```
def rand_tracker():
    rand_tracker.count += 1
    return random()
rand_tracker.count = 0
shuffle(v, random = rand_tracker)
print 'Random function was called %d times for length %d list.' % (rand_tracker.count, len(v))
```

Which shows:

```
Random function was called 999 times for length 1000 list.
```

What you should do instead is @abarnert's suggestion:

```
from random import Random
Random(4).shuffle(x)
```

In that case a fixed value is perfectly fine.

**TLDR**: Use the answer by @abarnert, do not use a fixed-value function for `random`!

Answer (score -2):

From the python [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

> The optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a
>   random float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, this is the function random()

You can use a lambda function that always returns the same value as a seed for `shuffle`:

```
In [7]: l = [1,2,3,4]
In [8]: random.shuffle(l, lambda: .5)

In [9]: l
Out[9]: [1, 4, 2, 3]

In [10]: l = [1,2,3,4]

In [11]: random.shuffle(l, lambda: .5)

In [12]: l
Out[12]: [1, 4, 2, 3]  # same order as Out[9]
```

Comment: It turns out this is a very bad idea and results in an almost unshuffled list for long lists! See my answer for details.

Comment: This is a **terrible** answer. Do not use the second argument to `random.shuffle()` to return a fixed value. You are no longer shuffling, you are producing a bad fixed swap sequence ill suited for real work. Use `random.seed()` instead before calling `random.shuffle()` with just one argument. See [Python shuffle(): Granularity of its seed numbers / shuffle() result diversity](//stackoverflow.com/q/48358500). The function passed in is called more than once, and should produce a new random value **each time**; a properly seeded RNG will produce the same 'random' sequence for a given seed.