# How to reuse one tensor when creating a tensorflow dataset iterator of a pair of tensors?

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

Imagine the case that I want to pair samples from one pool of data with samples from another pool of data together to feed into the network. But many samples from the first pool should be paired with the same sample in the second pool. (let's assume all samples are of the same shape).

For example, if we denote the samples from the first pool as f_i, samples from the second pool as g_j, I might want to have a mini-batch of samples as below (each line is one sample in the mini-batch):
(f_0, g_0)
(f_1, g_0)
(f_2, g_0)
(f_3, g_0)
...
(f_10, g_0)
(f_11, g_1)
(f_12, g_1)
(f_13, g_1)
...
(f_19, g_1)
...

If the data from the second pool are small (like labels), then I can simply store them together with samples from the first pool to tfrecords. But in my case the data from the second pool are of the same size as data from the first pool (for example, both are movie segments). Then saving them in pair in one tfrecords files seems to almost double the disk space use.

I wonder if there is any way in which I can only save all the samples from the second pool once on the disk, but still feed the data to my network as the way I wanted? (Assume I already have already specified the mapping between samples in the first pool and those from the second pool based on their file names).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an iterator for each one of the tfrecords (or pool of samples), so you get two iterators where each can iterate on its own pace. When you run `get_next()` on an iterator, the next sample is returned, so you have to keep it in a tensor and manually feed it. Quoting from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets):

> (Note that, like other stateful objects in TensorFlow, calling Iterator.get_next() does not immediately advance the iterator. Instead you must use the returned tf.Tensor objects in a TensorFlow expression, and pass the result of that expression to tf.Session.run() to get the next elements and advance the iterator.)

So all you need is a couple of loops that iterate and combine samples from each iterator as a pair, and then you can feed this when you run your desired operation. For example:

```
g_iterator = g_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
get_next_g = g_iterator.get_next()

f_iterator = f_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
get_next_f = f_iterator.get_next()

# loop g:
temp_g = session.run(get_next_g)
  # loop f:
  temp_f = session.run(get_next_f)
  session.run(train, feed_dict={f: temp_f, g: temp_g})
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hi @omar-hommos! Thanks a lot for your suggestion! If I understand correctly, the code example you gave would feed one example per time. Is this still possible for mini-batch larger than 1?    I have also got an impression that feed_dict would make the code inefficient because all the operations need to go through python again. But I am not sure if it is still true and whether this overhead is negligible.

Comment: Hi. This doesn't necessarily have to feed one example at a time. It depends on the construction of the samples you have. From your question:
(f_0, g_0) (f_1, g_0) (f_2, g_0) (f_3, g_0) ... (f_10, g_0). In this case, you can load a batch of 10x "f" and assign it a single label of "g" (still you need to make sure that the number of elements match, I believe). This can get easier or more complicated depending on constant your correspondences are; e.g. if you always have one label "g" to each 10x "f", then it's easy and can be written in an efficient way. Otherwise you might need some tricks

Comment: Regarding the use of feed_dict; from the quote in my answer, I get the impression that this is the only way to use tf Iterators, at least as of version 1.3. Since the whole purpose of developing the new Dataset API (which includes iterators) is performance/efficiency (in addition to usability), I believe you'd have no problem with efficiency. Using feed_dict is inefficient when you manually fill numpy arrays and feed them to the graph.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, with this API and using Iterators, the whole system/graph gets automatically optimized for stream processing of input data, so I believe you'd have no problems at all with the efficiency of the part that uses feed_dict with iterators. You still have to take care of efficiency of matching batches of "f" and "g", like discussed in the above comment.

Comment: @Mingbo Hi, if this answers your question, please label this as a correct answer. Otherwise, feel free to ask me any more questions or leave this question open for others to answer.

Comment: Hi @Omar, Thank you so much for your follow-up answers! I guess I was still not clear how to make the feed_dict suggestion work with tensorflow's dataset api or original queuing method for batching and random shuffling. It seems that if I ever include shuffling or batching, then I cannot guarantee that the samples from f are still paired with those from g that they are supposed to be paired with. Is it so? Sorry for my late reply.

Comment: It depends on how you do shuffling and your entire pipeline setup. If you have the same number of samples and labels, you can do the same shuffle on both datasets, then the shuffled output will also match. An example would be like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19307027/4359739).
As of batching, it also depends on your datasets. As I understand from your question, several videos share the same label. If so, you'll have to do some tricks to batch and shuffle everything. Can't think of a way from the top of my head but it's certainly doable.

Comment: @Mingbo you might also opt back to just saving everything in a single tfrecord even if it's more disk space, if development time and simplicity of the code is quite important to you; then the whole thing will become much easier. But then, it depends on your hardware limitations.

Comment: This another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19307329/4359739) seems like an even better method than the one I proposed two comments above,  to shuffle two datasets in the same way.

Comment: Thanks @Omar! I guess you are right, falling back to just saving everything in a single tfrecord is probably the simplest. In my case, hundreds of `f` correspond to the same `g`, and both `f` and `g` are large images.